# Only plainfile resource streams are supported stripe

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

**how to upload document file in stripe to verification.
i am using this code.**

```
 include_once(app_path() . '/Stripe/init.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(trans('lang_data.Secret_key'));
    $file = $r->file('image');
        $file_name = date('Ymdhis') . '.' . request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if(request()->image->move(public_path('image/payout_file'), $file_name)){
                $image = 'https://ufitpass.com/public/image/payout_file/'.$file_name;
                $filePath = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strstr($image, '/public');
                $filePurpose = 'identity_document';
                $fp = fopen($filePath, 'r');
                $account = \Stripe\File::create(
                      [
                        'purpose' => 'identity_document',
                        'file' => fopen($filePath, 'r'),
                      ],
                      [
                        'stripe_account' => trans('lang_data.Secret_key'),
                      ]
                    );

                echo '<pre>';print_r($account);die;
        }else{
            echo'error';
        }die;
```

**after compile this to response is**

> Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Only plainfile resource streams are supported in file /var/www/html/ultimateFitness/app/Stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line 39

Comment: You can't pass a HTTP link like that. You'd need to first download the image your server and save it to a local file, and then use a handle created with that local file path to `\Stripe\File::create` instead.

Comment: firstly i upload (move) image in my public folder then retrieve file from  public folder. 
after retrieve path is:
`$image = 'https://ufitpass.com/public/image/payout_file/'.$file_name;`

Comment: @VeerenderMishra you're not loading the image you're only creating a string that contains the URL to the resource.